# why my regular expression accepting square brackets when I not listed them

Tags: regex

In the regular expression `(?=^.{6,10}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:\'?&gt.&lt;,])(?!.*\\s).*$')`, why does `aA1!111]` pass? In the rule group for special characters `(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:\'?&gt.&lt;,])`, I have not escaped the square brackets so I suppose that anything between them should be accepted but not the square bracket themselves

Comment: Are you using this regex with a language like Java?  If not, what is your exact regex tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting/misunderstanding what a positive lookahead actually does.  The positive lookaheads in your regex require that certain characters be present, but they assert nothing regarding which characters *cannot* be present.  Here is slightly modified version of your regex:

```
^
    (?=.*\\d)                                       -- has a number
    (?=.*[a-z])                                     -- has lowercase
    (?=.*[A-Z])                                     -- has uppercase
    (?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:\'?&gt.&lt;,])   -- has a symbol
    (?!.*\\s)                                       -- has no whitespace
.{6,10}                                             -- between 6 and 10 characters
$
```

If you wanted to restrict your pattern to *not* allow square brackets, and possibly other characters, you could modify the `(?!.*\s)` negative lookahead term, e.g.

```
(?!.*[\s\]\[])
```

I am only escaping once here, for the sake of readability, but your regex language may require double escaping.

Comment: `(?=.*\\d)` is *"has a backslash and a `d`"*

Comment: @Tomalak [Not in Java](https://rextester.com/BRIO84202).  Depends on the language/tool being used, as I mentioned.

Comment: Also in Java. The regex and the string literal used to convey the regex are different things.

Comment: You are assuming that the code being presented in the original problem is pure regex, and _not_ code taken from some app language, e.g. Java.  I disagree with your assumption.  Why on earth would anyone want to assert a literal backslash followed by a number, when the rest of the pattern is clearly boilerplate password validation stuff?

Comment: You are assuming that the regex is being used in a Java string. I disagree with this assumption. ;) Nothing in the OPs post even hints at Java.

Comment: Yeah, it's nitpicking, I know. But when showing a regex without context, I think it should follow regex conventions only. This way it becomes less noisy & more usable to a variety of regex dialects. The double escaping strictly is a host language requirement and should not be included unless the sample regex is specifically written for the host language in question, i.e. given with context.

Comment: Thanks. I have opened another `SO` question on a new issue. I noticed that if the input is `aA1[11]`, even then the regex matches. I thought it shouldn't because the group `(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:'?&gt.&lt;,])` isn't satisfied. Link to new SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256757/regexp-test-not-giving-correct-result

Answer (score 0):

in order for the square brackets not to be accepted as the inputs, kindly include them in this category of characters: `(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:\'?&gt.&lt;,])`